Поиск элемента внутри iframe

Как найти в такой структуре выделенный элемент, cy.get("input#startDate") когда так указываю, то выходит ошибка


Скорее всего поиск не происходит потому, что поиск не проходит в документе iframe-ма. Воспользуйтесь свойством contentDocument у элемента iframe.

спасибо, помогло
